# What are the steps to get printing working during Bullseye install?

Tags: printing, debian-installer, deb

On Debian Buster, during the install process, I simply chose "Print server" from the short list of items to install (I believe in a component called the "tasksel"), and when I started the system and hit CTRL+P, it would find the printers connected to my Wifi router and immediately let me print. Basically, it installed my printer out-of-box with no other steps necessary, if I simply chose to install the "Print server" from the "Software selection" install menu.

[image]

On Debian Bullseye, I can no longer find an option to install a "Print server" or cups from tasksel while installing a fresh Debian install. Its missing from this list.

I tried installing all kinds of packages, especially those with "cups" in the name, yet when I go to print, the system cannot find any printers, except for "Print to PDF". Buster had a `task-print-server` file, but I can't find this in Bullseye.

What happened to the "Print server" option in tasksel? Is there an official way to really simply get printing working, as it was so easily under Buster?

Comment: Regarding *"the system cannot find any printer"*, have you already tried using `system-config-printer`? (I assume you can install it with `sudo apt install system-config-printer`).

Comment: `task-print-server` / `task-print-service` was removed, you can only pull CUPS in if you select a `task-*-desktop` package, see [THIS](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=950553) and [THIS](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=993668)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian has [removed the task in bullseye](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=950553) to reduce the number of printing related packages installed [sic].

To recreate what that task did, you should be able to run this in a terminal after the installation:

```
su root 
apt install --reinstall cups cups-bsd cups-client foomatic-db-engine hp-ppd hplip openprinting-ppds printer-driver-all
```

You need to be root to run the command.

I have tested these steps myself, and after installing these packages, my printer showed up in the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> menu of LibreOffice.

([Source 1](https://packages.debian.org/buster/task-print-server), [source 2](https://debian-facile.org/viewtopic.php?id=29332), [source 3](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=950553).)

Comment: A +500 bonus from scratch ! What a fabulous start you would achieve. Sincere congrats and my modest +10 in advance ! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! I feel it's time I started giving back to the community, I wouldn't be where I am without stackexchange! :)